# External SSD connected with adapter won't show up in Disk Utility

Tags: disk-utility, usb, ssd, sata

I recently bought an SSD ([SanDisk Plus, 480GB, 2.5", SATA III](https://www.emag.ro/solid-state-drive-ssd-sandisk-plus-480gb-2-5-sata-iii-sdssda-480g-g26/pd/DX13T2BBM/?X-Search-Id=b648a07b6f8197e1893e&X-Product-Id=16627796&X-Search-Page=1&X-Search-Position=2&X-Section=search&X-MB=0&X-Search-Action=view)) and tried to connect it to my [MacBook Pro (M1, 2020)](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP824) by chaining:

- a [USB 3.0-to-SATA III adapter](https://www.emag.ro/cablu-adaptor-usb-3-0-la-sata-3-22-pini-pt-hdd-ssd-2-5-inch-hard-disk-laptop-dv-04/pd/DCK2SXMBM/):

  [image]
- and a USB-3-to-USB-C [USB-C PRO Multiport Adapter](https://nextprovider.ro/index.php/mobile-accessories/multipurpose/hubs/usb-c-pro-multiport-adapter)

but the SSD doesn't appear in Disk Utility:

[image]

Windows doesn't recognize the SSD/adapter either:

[image]

This is what System Information reports:

[image]
[image]

The output of `ioreg -p IOUSB -w0 | sed 's/[^o]*o //; s/@.*$//'| grep -v 'Root.*'` is:

```
AppleT8103USBXHCI
USB2.0 Hub
USB2.0 Hub
IOUSBHostDevice
IOUSBHostDevice
USB3.0 Hub
USB 10/100/1000 LAN
AppleT8103USBXHCI
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Which USB-3-to-USB-C adapter do you use to connect the  USB 3.0-to-SATA III adapter to your Mac? Have you checked whether the  USB 3.0-to-SATA III adapter and disk work with another computer?

Comment: This is my adapter [link](https://nextprovider.ro/index.php/mobile-accessories/multipurpose/hubs/usb-c-pro-multiport-adapter). And that's what I got when I connected the hub with the ssd to a windows computer [link](https://imgur.com/a/Njc4KsR). Also thanks for the edit jaume.

Comment: On the website it says: Compatibility: WINDOWS / MAC OS 9.X / LINUX.

Comment: The adaptor is Mac OS 9.X compatible. I would not be surprised if this product is not be compatible with a M1 Mac running Big Sur or Monterey.

Comment: Mac OS 9 is from 25 years ago!

Answer (score 1):

The cable adapter was the problem